# Is there a way to send one message to each of my friends?

Tags: facebook

I'm planning to quit Facebook, and would like to send one single message to tell them how they can contact me in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to select all your friends at once and send message to them on Facebook as of now.

There is limit, [you can message up to 150 people at once](https://www.facebook.com/help/131313586947248/), and you have to select and put their name in recipient list one by one like you do for one friend.

Other option is, [create a secret group](https://www.facebook.com/help/220336891328465?helpref=about_content) and add all your friends (whom you want to send the message) into that group. Now post your message to the group, all your friends will get that message.

Answer (score 0):

"Messer: Command-line messaging for Facebook Messenger" could be helpful.

https://github.com/mjkaufer/Messer